# JavaCC lookahead option doesn't work

Tags: parsing, javacc, regex-lookarounds

I'm using JavaCC 6.0 and I need to set the lookahead option to 2 because of the following choice conflict:

```
double Func() :
{}
{
    <STRING> "(" ( (<STRING> | Expression() ) "," )*  ")"
}
```

The conflict exists because an `Expression()` can begin with a `<STRING>` and I'm getting "Consider using a lookahead of 2 for earlier expansion."

So I changed the lookahead option to
`options {
  LOOKAHEAD = 2;
  FORCE_LA_CHECK = true;
  ...}`

but I'm still getting the same warning and the parser fails when it needs to detect an expression instead of a string.

Am I doing something wrong or the lookahead option just doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never use a global setting of LOOKAHEAD other than 1.  Instead I would use a local look-ahead exactly where it is needed. In your case I would do the following

```
double Func() :
{}
{
    <STRING>
    "("
    ( 
         ( LOOKAHEAD( <STRING> "," )
           <STRING>
         | Expression()
         )
         ","
    )*
    ")"
}
```

It's rather odd that you require a comma after the final argument.  If you don't want that, you can do this

```
double Func() :
{}
{
    <STRING>
    "("
    ( 
         ( LOOKAHEAD( <STRING> ("," | ")") ) <STRING> | Expression() )
         (  ","
            ( LOOKAHEAD( <STRING> ("," | ")") ) <STRING> | Expression() )
         )*

    )?
    ")"
}
```

However, in both snippets above, these look-ahead specifications violate the advice in [FAQ 4.8](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/javacc-faq-moz.htm#tth_sEc4.8) that the tokens scanned by a syntactic look-ahead specification should all be consumed by the choice.  This could be a problem if you ever use `func()` itself in a look-ahead spec.  For the first syntax, this is easy to deal with: distribute the comma like this

```
double Func() :
{}
{
    <STRING>
    "("
    ( 
         ( LOOKAHEAD(<STRING> "," )
           <STRING> ","
         | Expression() ","
         )
    )*
    ")"
}
```

For the second syntax (the one without a comma after the last argument), you can use recursion like this:

```
double Func() :
{}
{
    <STRING> "("  ( ")" | Args() )
}

void Args() :
{}
    LOOKAHEAD(<STRING> ("," | ")" )
    <STRING>
    ("," Args() | ")" )
|   
    Expression()
    ("," Args() | ")" )
}
```

The recursive version also has the benefit that it has less repetition than the iterative version.